# Print News Headlines with Python/JSON

Tags: arrays, json

I'm having difficulty properly parsing an array.  I realize this is a newb error, so please forgive me.

Example:

```
import urllib2
import json
import sys


print "Good Morning, Rusty"
i = 0

print "From USA Today: Top Headlines"
f = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.usatoday.com/open/articles/topnews?encoding=json&api_key=98j............v5a93qs')
json_string = f.read()
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
for i in parsed_json[0]['stories']['title']:
        print json.dump(i)


f.close()
```

There's one major section called stories, and under it multiple occurrences of description, title, link, pubDate and several other fields.

I simply want to print the dozen or so titles presented by that JSON.

Comment: You can improve this question in two ways: 1. please tag the question with the programming language you're using. 2. give us a code snippet containing some sample json data that you're working with.

Comment: Yes, or whatever error you're encountering.

Comment: Here's a portion of the JSON dump:

Comment: {"stories":[{"description":"President Obama sought to recruit governors Monday in his sequester battle with Congress.","guid":[{"isPermalink":"true","value":"http:\/\/apidata.usatoday.com\/story\/news\/politics\/2013\/02\/25\/obama-biden-national-governors-association-sequester\/1946023\/?kjnd=f1adIicCxNHRxJQL6bDJr%2FNIlmEnFKyFJOTa4JQmM667%2FL3P2JOK4PKrCAefkF5r-407dc143-fb68-4df7-9f59-a8f579ed92c9_EgO9Ygi1KMQxlREpaZVhJqtprbDijMNhW9hQkdqyVOD2zsJ56%2BZ0bai46cfPR0MN"}],"link":"http:\/\/apidata.usatoday.com\/story\/news\/politics\/2013\/02\/25\/obama-biden-national-governors-association-sequester\

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did more learning and research, and at least got code that would print the top 5 headlines:

Here's what I solved this with:

```
json_string = f.read()
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
for i in range(6):
        title = parsed_json['stories'][i]['title']
        link = parsed_json['stories'][i]['link']
        print title
        print link
        print "-----------------------------------"
```